# How to submit Django form in the background by clicking a button?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am building an event registration website using django==2.1 . I have created views such that the admin can create events and the students can view these created events and click a button to participate in them. I have all the details of the logged in student. If a student clicks on the participate button, I want his roll and the event name (in whose detail page he clicked the button ) to be saved in the `EventParticipants` model given below:

```
class EventParticipants(models.Model):
    event_name = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant_roll = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='roll')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```

The current implementation I have takes the student to another page where he has to click another button to confirm his registration and submit the form. How can I store the data in the model without redirecting the user?

Comment: remove `def get_absolute_url(self):`

Comment: @Ahtisham I have written that as the user is submitting the form in another page and want him to be redirected on successful submission. I want a way by which I can submit the form in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `jQuery` and `AJAX` in this case. I would suggest the following:

#### urls.py

Create a url for enrolling/participating which will be called via an AJAX request example:

```
urlpatterns  [
...
    path('participate-in-event/<int:event_id>/', Participate.as_view(), name='participate'),
...
]
```

#### views.py

```
from django.views import View


class Participate(View):
    def get(self, request, event_id)
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                enrollment = EventParticipants.objects.create(event_name=event, participant_roll=request.user.student)
                return JsonResponse({'enrolled': 1, 'message': 'Successfully enrolled', 'event':event.name}, status=200)
            except Exception as ex:
                return JsonResponse({'enrolled': 0, 'messsage': str(ex), 'event': event.name}, status=403)
```

#### html

In the template where the events are listed, you can list them like the following example(but you are not only limited to it, its just another way, you can modify as you want.

```
{% for event in events %}
    <h1>{{ event.name }}</h1>
    <a class='participate-link' href='javascript:void(0)' data-url="{{ url 'participate' event.id }}"> Participate in this event</a>
{% endfor %}

...
<!-- include jquery here -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('.participate-link').bind('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json'
                data: {},
                success: function(response){
                    alert(repsonse.message + 'Event: ' + response.event);
                },
                fail: function(data){alert(data.message)}
            });
        });
    });
```

> **Note:** In the `Participate()` view, i assumed the student model has a one-to-one relationship with the default django User object